# change EJS varaibles without refreshing the page Nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, request, bootstrap-modal

so I have this problem, Im trying to build a website in which people can give out links which I will then analyze using request-promise.js (so on the server side) . This analysis will try to find embed videos in the given link. If present I want to make that emebed video appear in an iframe on my current page.

So for now Ive managed to get the embed the video, and render it in an EJS template variable , but this means that I have to use res.render('page', variables) and from my understanding that means reloading the page.

What I want to know is if there is a way to do that without reloading the page ?

(my goal is to make the found video appear in a bootstrap modal div that appears after people gave the link and clicked on my upload button that trigers the scrapping of the given link)

Thanks for your help

Pardon me if my question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `XMLHttpRequest` to get the data from the server asynchronously and display/store them on the page without reloading the whole page.

```
var url = '/get-embed-video/'+link;
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
        // here get the response from the server
        // and display your data
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check the doc of this right away. Thanks a lot